# Android ran out of memory after "notifyDataSetChanged()" in getCount()

Tags: java, android

I have pageAdapter created in mainActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.setContext(this);

    try {
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("myLOG", e.toString());
    }
```

As well i have SingleItemActivity which opens when i click on listViewItem:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SingleItemActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("id", id);
                            intent.putExtra("listViewID", 1);
                            startActivity(intent);
```

I have 2 lists in 2 tabs and when I tap on some item in 1st list - it opens normally, but when I open a second tab and tap on some item from where android talks me:

```
The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 2, found: 1
```

Ok, I was change getCount method to:

```
@Override
        public int getCount() {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return Cache.jsonData[listViewID].length();
        }
```

So, when I try to open item from any list android shows me :

```
Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 28 byte allocation with 4 free bytes and 4B until OOM"
```

Someone can help? Thanks for reading my bad English))

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error explains, after you change the contents of the ArrayList, you need to tell the list that the source of the data had changed and it needs to redraw itself to show the new data.

So, that is where notifyDatasetChanged() comes in. It tells the ListView that the data has been modified; and to show the new data, the ListView must be redrawn.

I am not sure what you mean by "Tabs", but chances are you are not using notifyDataSetChanged() in the right place. If you are using an action bar tab with contents returned from a completely different activity or fragment (and it sounds like you are), you have to use notifyDataSetChanged() of the action bar adapter  in the code of the activity which has to return the data. For example,

```
@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    { 
        case R.id.action_new_forward:

            FragmentTab2.mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//this updates the adapter in my action bar tab 
            Intent ina = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            ina.putExtra("stra", values1);
            startActivity(ina);// This is the code to start the parent activity of my action bar tab(fragment).
    } 
}
```

This activity would return some data to FragmentTab2 and it would directly update listview in FragmentTab2.

Answer (score 0):

because `notifyDataSetChanged();` called `getCount()`and in your case, call `notifyDataSetChanged();`, etc

so just split the 2 calls

Answer (score -1):

if your adapter is not `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, you should use it, for getCount use :

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
```

but for getItemPosition use:

```
@Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment)object;
        int position = items.indexOf(fragment.getItem());

        if(position >= 0) {
            fragment.pudDataChanges();
            return position;
        } else return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

Then use:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
        fragment.setItem(items.get(position));
        return fragment;
    }
```

And in your fragment:
`setItem(Item item)` is used for sotre any changes, and `putDataChanges()` is for get that changes from `Item` and use it

That will work surely